# ARM Assembly - getting next character in a loop

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to be able to create an assembly program that takes in a file and loops through the characters in the file and prints them. **How can I use fgetc to get the character?** I feel like I need to store the character and then use another function to print

Code:

```
.global fgetc
.global start

.data
    filein: .asciz "filein.txt"
    read: .asciz "r"

.text

start: 
    PUSH {R1}
    LDR R0, [R1, #0x04]
    LDR R1, =read

    BL fopen

    LDR R1, =filein
    STR R0, [R1]
    POP {R1}
    B loop


loop:
    LDR R1, = filein @load R1 with the address of filein
    LDR R0, [R1] @load pointer to R1 into R0
    BL fgetc


endloop:


exit:
```

How could I use BL fgetc to get the next character in the file? or would that line of code just do that?

I want to be able to get this character and store it in an array and then print the array. I'm taking this step by step so **I would just like to know how to get the next character in the file.**

As you can see I've not started the endloop and exit function. I've not been doing ARM assembly for long so if there are any errors or bad coding practices please comment.

Apologies for this question being really vague, I'm new to assembly and still trying to grasp concepts.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Yup, you can use `fputc`.  Have a look at [C compiler output](http://goo.gl/PNiSza) for a fgetc/fputc loop.  Look up the calling convention used on ARM to understand which registers to put args in, and which regs are call-preserved vs. call-clobbered.

Answer (score 0):

Function `fgetc` gets the file pointer and returns an integer. So it will read `r0` and return the value to `r0`.

So in your case it will work, as your can read the result in `r0`.

A remark for the code: you should read the file pointer before the loop do not do it each time and store it to a temporary register.